# Angular 2 unit testing with VMware Clarity modules

Tags: angular, unit-testing, vmware-clarity

I'm doing a POC for an angular 2 project that's using VMware's Clarity components.  When I run the test runner, I'm getting the following errors:

```
'clr-main-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'clr-main-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'clr-main-container' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<clr-main-container>
```

I'm new to angular 2 and I'm not able to find anything on Google.

Comment: Hi @agillette. It looks like you have not registered `ClarityModule`. Need more details to understand the complete issue. Whats the test runner? Are you using the Clarity seed project? I would recommend going through the Clarity get started page: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/get-started#seedProjectClarity and using their seed app.

Answer (score 2):

Hi [agillette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6363266/agillette),
you are probably missing the Testbed configuration in your tests. Something like:

```js
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {ClarityModule} from 'clarity-angular';

describe('...', function() {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ClarityModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [YourTestComponent]
    });
  });

});
```

You can read more about the TestBed [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#testbed).

Also feel free to check out the [Clarity seed](https://github.com/vmware/clarity-seed) for a simple working application with testing wired in.